# Jquery play/pause toggle with rollover

Tags: jquery, toggle, rollover

I have a jQuery script for a slideshow play/pause button that toggles between two images on click. Is there a way to add a rollover state to the separate images that are being toggled between?

Here's the script:

```
$(".play").toggle(
function () {
$(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-play.png"});
},
function () {
$(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-pause.png"}); 
}
);
```

Here's the site: http://www.beta.erickdoxey.com (work in progress). The previous and next buttons have the rollover state that I would like to achieve with the pause/play button. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a class to the play button and then detect that class on hover. What I mean is:

```
$(".play").toggle(function () {
    $(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-play.png"}).addClass('paused');
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-pause.png"}).removeClass('paused'); 
});
```

Then you can detect it on hover like so:

```
 if (this).hasClass('paused') {
    $(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-play-hover.png"})
 } else {
    $(this).find("img").attr({src:"images/btn-pause-hover.png"})
 }
```

You can further use that class for other things later too.

Comment: The addClass and removeClass solution worked great, but the hover event method wasn't quite working correctly. I used a mouseenter and mouseout event instead. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I normally find mouseenter and mouseout easier to work with too.